# Ember Add value to a Foreign Key field in Django Rest API

Tags: ember.js, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Department(models.Model):
   dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)
   section_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)    

class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
   dept = models.ForeignkeyField(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, required=True)
   addr = models.TextField(required=True)
```

I want to input a value to the User model from `Ember front end` using a form, Then how can I give the value to `dept` field ?
*(assume that the Department model is already populated)*

Comment: What do your ember models look like?

Comment: also what does your api look like? what kind of format? json? `{ json:api }`?